# MongoDb text search with language support

Tags: mongodb

I have problems with the language text search of MongoDB. For some records the search works great and for some records it does not work at all.

I have a list of ingredients that I would like to search. The ingredients are in several languages and I like to take care of singular and plural.

Here is my example

**Schema**

```json
{
  translation: [
    {
      language: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
  ],
  calories: {
    "type": Number
  },
  protein: {
    "type": Number
  },
  carbohydrate: {
    "type": Number
  },
  fat: {
    "type": Number
  }
}
```

**Index**

```
foodSchema.index( { "translation.name": "text" }, { default_language: "german" } )
```

**Read Index from DB**

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "translation.name_text",
        "default_language" : "german",
        "background" : true,
        "weights" : {
            "translation.name" : 1
        },
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

**Records**

```
{
  calories: 1,
  protein: 2,
  carbohydrate: 3,
  fat: 4,
  translation: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId('5fba87d13ad6404108191670'),
      language: 'german',
      name: 'gurke'
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId('5fba87d13ad6404108191671'),
      language: 'english',
      name: 'cucumber'
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId('5fba87d13ad6404108191672'),
      language: 'spanish',
      name: 'pepino'
    }
  ]
}

// ----

{    
  calories: 4,
  protein: 3,
  carbohydrate: 2,
  fat: 1,
  translation: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId('5fba87d13ad6404108191674'),
      language: 'german',
      name: 'huhn'
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId('5fba87d13ad6404108191675'),
      language: 'english',
      name: 'chicken'
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId('5fba87d13ad6404108191676'),
      language: 'spanish',
      name: 'pollo'
    }
  ]
}
```

**Searching data**

```js
db.getCollection('foods').find({$text: { $search: "gurke" }}) //works
db.getCollection('foods').find({$text: { $search: "gurken" }}) //works
db.getCollection('foods').find({$text: { $search: "cucumber" }}) //works
db.getCollection('foods').find({$text: { $search: "cucumbers" }}) //works
db.getCollection('foods').find({$text: { $search: "huhn" }}) //works
db.getCollection('foods').find({$text: { $search: "hühner" }}) //works
db.getCollection('foods').find({$text: { $search: "chicken" }}) // no result
db.getCollection('foods').find({$text: { $search: "chickens" }}) //no result
db.getCollection('foods').find({$text: { $search: "pepino" }}) //no result
```

The documentation from MongoDb says: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/

> The default language associated with the indexed data determines the
> rules to parse word roots (i.e. stemming) and ignore stop words.

- Does it means that only the default language is supported?
- Why is it working for cucumber but not for chicken?

I was also checking the stop words for any chicken. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the index, that's correct, but you need to add `$language` or it uses the default language (at least when using `$text`).
Try

```
 db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"pollo", $language:"spanish"}})
```

[`$language` Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html)

> If not specified, the search uses the default language of the index.

Also, if you run

```
 db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"pollo"}}).explain()
```

You'll find out the query is using the default language.

Comment: you're welcome. good luck w that project. seems interesting.  @TobiasBenkner

Comment: the conversation goes even more into the depths here. [MongoDB Regex search with language / translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971224/mongodb-regex-search-with-language-translation)

Comment: busy now but either me later or someone else will help you out :-) @TobiasBenkner